# Euler function formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Given that $e\ge1$ and $p$ is prime. Prove that

$$\varphi\left(p^e\right) = p^e\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$

---

We pick some $a\in\{0,1,\ldots,p^e-1\}$ which may be written as
$$a=a_e+a_{e-1}p+\ldots+a_1p^{e-1}.$$

Where each $a_i\in\{0, \ldots, p-1\}$ for all $i$. Now $\varphi(n)$ counts the number of coprimes from $0$ to $n-1$, hence we require

$${\rm gcd}(a,p^e) = 1 \iff {\rm gcd}(a,p) = 1 \iff a_e\not=0.$$

$$\implies \varphi(p^e) = (p-1)p^{e-1} = p^e\left(1-\frac1p\right)$$

However I'm slightly confused on the final step.. How is $p-1$ and $p^{e-1}$ found?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $a_e$ can be chosen in $p-1$ ways, anything from $1$ to $p-1$.

All the other $a_i$ (and there are $e-1$ possibilities for $i$) can be chosen in $p$ ways. So there are $p^{e-1}$ choices for these.

I think it is simpler to note that we want all numbers between $1$ and $p^e$ **except** for the $p^{e-1}$ of them that are divisible by $p$. It follows that $\varphi(p^e)=p^e-p^{e-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\gcd(a,p^k)\neq 1\implies a=kp$$
with $k\in \{1,...,p^{k-1}\}$, and thus, there is $p^{k-1}$ such number. Therefore $$|\{a\in \mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z \mid \gcd(a,p^k)=1\}|=|\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z-\{a\in\mathbb Z/p^n\mathbb Z\mid \gcd(a,p^k)\neq 1\}|=p^n-p^{n-1}=p^{n-1}(1-p)=p^n\left(\frac{1}{p}-1\right).$$